How can I change camera view of MuJoCo simulation?
I am working on a robot simulation using a MuJoCo (ver.3.1.1) with C++ language.
And I am trying to change the default camera view of simulation, but I have a trouble in this work.
My project composed of files and folders as below and there's no problem in build/run.
|- build
|- cmake
|- include
  |- mujoco
  |- array_safety.h
  |- ...
  |- simulate.h
|- model
  |- assets
  |- robot.xml
|- src
  |- glfw_adpater.cc
  |- ...
  |- main.cc
  |- simulate.cc
|- CMakeLists.txt

What I'm trying is to change the default camera view of simulation as I stated.
So, I tried to change main.cc code as below, but the camera view doesn't change.
(I referred to "how to change the angle of camera" issue.)

main.cc

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  // ...

  mjvCamera cam;
  mjv_defaultCamera(&cam);

  //*********************** I added code here ********************
  double viewer[] = { -90.95, -6.25, 1.85, -0.089, 0.001, 0.102 };
  cam.azimuth = viewer[0];
  cam.elevation = viewer[1];
  cam.distance = viewer[2];
  cam.lookat[0] = viewer[3];
  cam.lookat[1] = viewer[4];
  cam.lookat[2] = viewer[5];
  //***************************************************************

  mjvOption opt;
  // ...
}

When I build this code and check the values of cam in simulate.cc, it is found that the changed value didn't reflected.

RenderLoop function in simulate.cc

void Simulate::RenderLoop()
{
  // ...
  mjv_defaultCamera(&this->cam);
  mjv_defaultOption(&this->opt);
  InitializeProfiler(this);
  InitializeSensor(this);

  printf("azimuth: %f\n", this->cam.azimuth); // 90.0 is printed
  // ...
}

I would appreciate if you give me an advice for this.
Sincerely,
I also tried to directly change cam values in simulate.cc as below, but the changed value didn't reflected in visualization too.

RenderLoop function in simulate.cc

void Simulate::RenderLoop()
{
  // ...
  mjv_defaultCamera(&this->cam);
  mjv_defaultOption(&this->opt);
  InitializeProfiler(this);
  InitializeSensor(this);

  this->cam.azimuth = -90.95;

  printf("azimuth: %f\n", this->cam.azimuth);
  // -90.95 is printed but the there's no change in visualization
  // ...
}


FYI, I found that I have to write this->cam.azimuth = -90.0 in the while loop of Simulate::RenderLoop function
